# Determine an array submit button using javascript then outputs data using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a list of fetched data, and to every data has a form below it, like a comment box form, where other users can leave a message to the specific data.

What I've tried so far is putting the submit button into an array to distinguish it from one to another (don't know if I'm doing this right as this is one of my first attempt in using *Javascript/jQuery library* and *AJAX*).

I can submit the data and insert it into the *SQL* database just by using *PHP/MySQL* but I wanted to achieve at least the comment-like system of this community, *Stackoverflow*, wherein once a comment is posted, it would show up right after hitting the button (not by reloading the whole page in order to submit the data into the database).

This is the dynamically post data:

```
<?php while($loopquery){ ?>
   <div>
      <?php echo $row['data']; ?>
      <div id="flash[]"></div> <!-- NEW POSTED COMMENT SHOULD BE SHOWN HERE -->
      <form action="#" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="comment[]" id="comment[]">
      <input type="submit" id="submit[]">
      </form>
   </div>
<?php } /* END OF LOOP */ ?>
```

And once the submit is clicked:

```
$(function () {
    var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    for (var a = 0; a < submit.length; a++) {
        submit[a].click(function () {
            var comment = document.getElementById('comment');
            var hiddentaskid = document.getElementById('hiddentaskid');
            var dataString = '&comment='+comment[a]+'&hiddentaskid='+hiddentaskid[a];
            if (comment[a] == '' || hiddentaskid[a] == '') {
                alert('Please Give Valid Details');
            } else {
                var flash = document.getElementById('flash');
                flash[a].show();
                flash[a].fadeIn(400).html('Loading message');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "commentajax.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) {
                        $("ol#update").append(html);
                        $("ol#update li:last").fadeIn("slow");
                        flash[a].hide();
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

I've tried using array to distinguish the data from one to another, but it's not working when I try to tweak the script. New posted message/comment should pop-out in the `<div ="flash"></div>` area (by using ***AJAX***). Can anyone help me how I can achieve my wanted output?

Comment: What was the problem afterall? dID YOU GET AN ERROR ON YOUR CODE?

Comment: @HTTP - There's no error. But if I remove the array on the *HTML attributes* and in the *script*, comment would show up to all the data instead of just showing up on the current post.

Comment: Your post is similar to this post you need to pass variable when posting data via ajax for more details visit this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557075/passing-url-params-with-jquery-into-php/25557666#25557666

Comment: Would it not be better to just have a hidden form field in there that posts the id of the form submitted... it should not be an array you'r not posting multiple together E.G `<input type="hidden" name="inreplyto" value="$commentId">`

Comment: @MartinBarker - Inserting data into the database was not my problem. My problem was the calling of ajax.

Comment: ids have to be unique. use class instead of ids as you are using them inside loops..

Comment: @GrandMarshalBraev well if thats the case you could have just used Malsup's ajaxForm, http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ more people should know about this it's awesome :)

Answer (score 3):

Check out this fiddle. 
   http://jsfiddle.net/7xjqzmqz/

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xjqzmqz/4/)
Note I'm using Jquery

It isn't using your code specifically, but hopefully it gets the point across.

Replace the url field with where you plan to POST to.

```
//message is just an object to keep the comment
var message = {name: 'Gabs00'};


$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    //stop page reload
    e.preventDefault();

    //Using $(this), target this specific form
    message.comment = $(this).find('.message').val();
    var json = JSON.stringify(message);

    //Finding the parent div, to make sure I append only to this forms comment list
    var $parent = $(this).closest('.item-to-comment');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data:{json: json},
        success: function(resp){

            //Traversing back down the dom
            var $ul = $parent.find('.comments');

            $ul.find('li').removeClass('special');
            $ul.append('<li class="special">' + resp.name + ': ' +
                       resp.comment + '</li>');
        }

    })

});
```

Comment: Sorry for getting back to this question too late. I've tried your answer on my project but it does not show anything, but if I remove the content of url (*/echo/json*), it will show up *undefined: undefined* instead of the *user's name* and its *message*. I also wanted to insert the message into my database. And you answer also disables the other form on my page, like the search bar. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @GrandMarshalBraev sorry I did not mention it, but the `echo/json` is just for jsfiddle and ajax. You would need to replace that url with the appropriate url for your site. I wasn't aware of the additional forms on you page. You can add a class to your comment forms and replace form in `$('form')` with the class name. fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7xjqzmqz/4/)

Comment: I've tried replacing the URL with the page itself, but it still shows *undefined: undefined.* Care to explain more on that part?

Comment: @GrandMarshalBraev try the docs for the ajax call here [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: How can I get the POST data? I changed the *url* to my insert query page, but it does not work. I had my *form name* set to array `[]` and then on my insert query, I checked the array which has the content, and when found, it will be the one to be inserted into my database. But seems not to work.

Comment: +1 My current problem with this answer right now was the repeated comment. The project I was building right now has the aspect of typical social medias right now. Home page consists of latest activities, so I use ajax to fetch new data/activities once the user reach the end of the page. Problem right now is when I try to put a comment into the *newly ajax fetched data*, it will repeat the comment, twice or up to 4 times. It looks like this answer is not compatible with my other ajax.

Comment: @GrandMarshalBraev You may want to post another for that with some code. It sounds like all of the comments are being reloaded, but the old data isn't being emptied from the dom elements first.