# data passing on the same page using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am stuck while passing the input values to same page for that i used Ajax but it is not happening and here my ajax function not working and i think its all because of URL given in the below code.

Just tell me, what should I insert in url section so that I can pass the values on the same page.

Please suggest your thoughts on the same.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#saveForm', function()
 {

  var data = $(this).serialize();

  $.ajax({

  type : 'POST',

  url  : 'index.php',

  data : data,

  success :  function(data)
       {

      $("#saveForm").fadeOut(500).hide(function()

      {
       $(".result").fadeIn(500).show(function()

       {
        $("#demo").html(data);
       });
      });

       }
  });
  return false;
 });
```

Comment: Your URL is wrong, its calling `index.php`, it need to be something like `controllerName/methodName` replace your controller and method name

Comment: How do you know he's using mvc, or similar? It's a simple jquery function he's showed us, unless I've missed something.

Comment: Why the URL must be like this ? If he uses a PHP framework maybe. Try to look to your console, you will have the status of your request.

Comment: @GaneshGhalame How can You know that? It is fully possible to let `index.php` or any PHP script handle the POST input. However "not happening" and "not working" is too little information. Please give us more information. What errors are you seeing? What should be the URL of the script to handle the POST data?

Comment: @mfisher91  +1 I am wrong, I tried to guess, Manish Mishra please give us details

Comment: If you want to send ajax data to same url, not set `url` property in your `$.ajax`

Comment: same solution can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557075/passing-url-params-with-jquery-into-php/25557666#25557666